# Load content in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

Currently I am facing a problem with Jquery ajax call. The Ajax call in my jsp takes more time to load data where as javascript form submit takes less time.

Using javascript form submit i am unable to load the content form result in another tab.
Could any one help me on this

Javascript Function

```
         function getCircuitMaintenanceDetails(event,refno)
          {   
              var eve = event;
              var ref_no = refno;
              var url = "circuitMaintenanceDetails.do?EVENT_KEY="+eve+"&REF_NO="+ref_no; 
              document.getElementById('sessReferenceId').value=refno;
             $.ajax({
                  type:'post',
                  cache:false,
                  url:url,
                  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                      $('#content02').html('<div class="loading"><center><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /><center></div>');
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       window.scrollTo(0,0); 
                       $('#content02').html(data);                              
                   }
              }); 


          }
```

Above javascript function loads data in another tab using ajax call. It takes more time

The jsp code has been placed in http://jsfiddle.net/mJ8m3/

I am using IE8 and Jquery 1.7.1 in my jsp file. Any one guide me how to improve the performance of Ajax call or could guide me how to load data in second tab ie (content02) tab using javascript function.

If I use document.forms[0].submit is loading the content in the same tab instead of tab2.

After Submitting the form in javascript I am unable to load the content in another tab defined using div tag

Any one can help me in this problem. Really need a solution for this. Help me to increase the speed

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's **load()** method.

Comment: Its also consume more time. Its performance is same as jquery ajax

Comment: iam attaching a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zAVLV/6/    Let's see if it is of any help.

Comment: You can also use datatables instead. They are fast and efficient and work great with jquery. Use below link http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. My result is displaying fast. Once the resultset is populated if i click on the value it has to load its details in the second tab which consumes more time.. Help me in the ajax call where i have attached my snippet above for loading the data in tab